# MethodName(out IntPtr variableName) send null values for out parameter from the iOS Binding dll in .NET 8

Tags: maui, .net-7.0, .net-8.0, maui-ios

GeList(out IntPtr variableName) send null values for out parameter from the iOS Binding dll in .NET 8 .NET 8 iOS binding library project . Method in ApiDefinition class.

```
//iOS Binding Library Project ApiDefinition.cs 
// @required -(RESULT)getList:(NSMutableArray **)availableList; 
[Export("getList:")] Result getList(out IntPtr availableList);
```

in .NET 7 if we call above method in MAUI SAMPLE APP the availableList will received.

```
// MAUI app 
//Get avilable List 
NSMutableArray availableList = new NSMutableArray(); 
IntPtr availableHandle = availableList.Handle; 
Result availableListResult = apiInstance.getList(out availableHandle); 
availableList = ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject<NSMutableArray>(availableHandle); 
if (availableListResult == Result.Success) 
{ 
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Success " + availableList);
 }
```

But in .NET 8 if we call above method in MAUI SAMPLE APP the availableList will get **Null** , but not in .Net 7 (can get availableList ). Any solution for .Net 8 ?.

In .NET 8 if I call getList method in MAUI SAMPLE APP the availableList will get **Null** , but not in .Net 7 (can get availableList )

Comment: You should probably raise a bug with MAUI team

Comment: Have you tried to add this to your consuming csproj, see [.NET 8 iOS binding to NSString returns null](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/20061#issuecomment-1954073282)

Comment: Hi All, Microsoft offers a solution for the .NET 8 iOS binding DLL. It's important to note that in the method signature, you should utilize "ref" instead of "out". While "out" will function in .NET 7, for .NET 8, it's recommended to use "ref".
ex:- string MethodTestDoublePointer(ref IntPtr nameList);

Comment: @S.D.Adrian Good to see you've figured it out, you can post it as an answer as it may help others facing the same issue.